# Выравнивание заголовков разных блоков

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как сделать,чтобы при увеличении размера заголовка, текст не выходил за красную зону снизу и оставался на одной линии с другими заголовками ? (В коде я прописал свойства для row, т.к. здесь классы bootstrap-а не пашут).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.contacts p{
 margin-bottom: 0;
 padding-bottom: 9px;
}

.contacts__title{
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 22px;
 color: #0f5f5c;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.contacts__email{
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #0f5f5c;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.contacts__phone{
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #83a7a5;
}

.contacts__address{
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #83a7a5;
 width: 188px;
}

.footer__item p{
 margin-bottom: 0;
 padding-bottom: 9px;
}

.item__title{
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #0f5f5c;

}

.item__selection{
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #83a7a5;
}

.item__selection:hover{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #83a7a5;
}

.row{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}

.footer__item{
  margin-left:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4">
            <div class="contacts">
              <h3 class="contacts__title">sharik</h3>
              <p class="contacts__email">@: hi@sharik.com</p>
              <p class="contacts__phone">p: +62 200 580 0117</p>
              <p class="contacts__address">a: 601 Overlook Circle Suite 290
              Kalam, MI 49009</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4">
            <div class="footer__item">
              <h3 class="item__title">Company</h3>
              <p><a href="#" class="item__selection">Home</a></p>
              <p><a href="#" class="item__selection">About Us</a></p>
              <p><a href="#" class="item__selection">Pricing</a></p>
              <p><a href="#" class="item__selection">Contact Us</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4">
            <div class="footer__item">
              <h3 class="item__title">Others</h3>
              <p><a href="#" class="item__selection">Help & Support</a></p>
              <p><a href="#" class="item__selection">Privacy Policy</a></p>
              <p><a href="#" class="item__selection">Terms</a></p>
              <p><a href="#" class="item__selection">Sitemap</a></p>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не применял Bootstrap чего и Вам желаю

В общем обнулил все `margin` и `padding` у заголовков и так же (плохая практика) уменьшил высоту линии у тега `h3`

Для проверки поставил псевдоэлемент с 1px высотой, по которой выравнивал заголовки второго и третьего уровня

> Если что то не так скажите - по любому достигнем нужного результата

```css
html,
body,
.items,
.item,
h2,
h3,
p,
a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  display: block;
}

h2,
h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  line-height: 0.5;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 30px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.items:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 44px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: red;
}

p,
a {
  padding: 6px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <h2>sharik</h2>
    <div style="margin-top: 3px;">
      <p>@: hi@sharik.com</p>
      <p>p: +62 200 580 0117</p>
      <p>a: 601 Overlook Circle Suite 290<br> Kalam, MI 49009</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h3>Company</h3>
    <div style="margin-top: 12px;">
      <a href="">Home</a>
      <a href="">About Us</a>
      <a href="">Pricing</a>
      <a href="">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h3>Others</h3>
    <div style="margin-top: 12px;">
      <a href="">Help & Support</a>
      <a href="">Privacy Policy</a>
      <a href="">Terms</a>
      <a href="">Sitemap</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я решил вопрос путем добавления margin-top : -9 px. Но спасибо,что дали ответ на мой вопрос :)